# Rails routing: cannot differentiate static and dynamic routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create custom URLs for my site's users:

```
www.mysite.com/user1
```

If I set the routing rule to be this:

```
match ':id' => "user#view", :as => :user
```

Then it works great! I can access www.mysite.com/user1 and it will pull up the page for user1.

However, that breaks my about page, which is at www.mysite.com/about . The error I get here is:
    "Couldn't find User with id=about"

Any idea how I can fix this problem? Thanks! As an aside - I'm using friendlyid to generate the human readable slugs.

Ringo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the about page a static file located at `public/about.html`? If so, then Rails will match this first and fall back to the router if it can't find the file.

If it's a route instead, then your `match :id` route should be *beneath* the one for about, so that about is matched first.